# What is the difference between 家{うち}の子{こ}供{ども} versus 私{わたし}の子{こ}供{ども}?

Tags: word-choice

I have no idea what the answer is for the following question.
What is the difference between 家{うち}の子{こ}供{ども} versus 私{わたし}の子{こ}供{ども} ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

家の~ or 私の~ is basically the same thing with the former stressing on that its yours. You can see it as if the stress is on one's own. You can use it even in the context when the object does not belong to your family. Like 家の会社 or 家の上長{じょうちょう}.

Consider 家の as something is member of one's (whatever group) you want to refer to.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's rather like the difference between "my daughter" and "our daughter". These can only ever refer to the same person, but the shades of meaning are different. 家の~ is a bit informal, but it's very common in speech. 「私の息子は...」 sounds a bit formal, and it's also redundant, since 「息子は...」 would mean the same thing.

PS: A nearby native speaker (うちの三男, actually) points out that it would be more natural to write 家 in hiragana.

Comment: For the OP:  this is correct about writing うち in hiragana, because the kanji is more likely to be 内 than 家 anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I agree too. Writing うちin Kanji seems a little unnatural too.